# can i skip location permission using RxAndroidBle?

Tags: rxandroidble

i want to use this [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle) library without location permission as my bluetooth device is not a beacon device. so can i scan devices without location permission?

Answer (score 1):

No — you cannot perform a BLE scan on Android 6.0+ devices without `Location Permissions` as the beacons *will* get scanned even if your device is not a beacon.

Since Android 6.0 the OS requires `Location Permissions` to be granted to use the BLE scans. Even more some devices require `Location Services` to be on to return scan results — if `Location Services` are off the scan starts normally but does not callback with any scanned devices.

There is one workaround. One may use classic Bluetooth discovery and filter for BLE devices. The downside is that in this way `BLE Advertisement Data` is not accessible.

Comment: Can i  use classic Bluetooth discovery using this library?

Comment: This library does not support Bluetooth Classic scans